Como modifico la version de AGP en Android Studio?
estoy haciendo un proyecto y me salto lo siguiente:

Intente configurarlo pero no se pudo

Quise usar el asistente pero no me figura

Alguno sabria como hacer? Gracias
Intente sincronizar pero me salto eso, busque solucion en documentacion pero no funciono

Quizás y esto te ayude ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880154/agp-upgrade-assistant-window-not-opening-in-android-studio/70971871#70971871

Pruebs presionando 2 veces el tabulador y buscar ahí el asistente.

Es importante que primero revises la tabla de compatibilidad.

Dentro del archivo build.gradle en el bloque dependencies , define la versión adecuada
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:<versión-adecuada>'
}

También puedes abrir el asistente de actualización AGP, ve a Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant:


Trata de hacer lo siguiente.
Dentro del IDE, en la barra de navegación vertical de la derecha, busca el icono de Gradle y, en el icono del engranaje, selecciona "Gradle Settings".

Se te abrirá una ventana y, en Gradle JDK, selecciona "jdr-17".

Aplica los cambios, y trata de buildear de nuevo el proyecto.

Hola! No funciono, sigue saliendo de la misma forma :(, muchas gracias por tu aporte igualmente

¿Qué versión de Android Studio estás utilizando?

Estoy usando android studio ladybug
